# Page Extends Beyond HTML Tag

Tags: html, css, overflow

This is completely different from the regular overflow issues people struggle with. First of all, I've only been able to produce this issue in Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.101 64-bit). IE 9+ and Firefox seem to behave as expected.

The body element grow with the content. No `height: 100%` or `position: absolute` styling used here.
The problem is that there seems to be something unknown forcing the browser to scroll further than it should by roughly 400px or more on both x and y axis. The inspector cannot select anything in this empty space and ends up selecting the html tag.
I've been through every element on the page and nothing seems to extend beyond the html tag!

Unfortunately I cannot link anything as the site is on a work server and requires authentication to access the page :(
I'm stumped, so *any* suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you could reproduce it in a test page on a public server?

Comment: At this point in time I have no idea how to!
I'm poking about trying to figure out the minimum elements, style, meta tags, etc that will reproduce the issue.
I'm fully aware how little I'm giving people to work with here :(
Will post more info as it becomes available. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Some things you could try 1) Incognito mode 2) A fresh Chrome browsing profile 3) A CSS reset. Just throwing things out there for you.

Comment: Ok, the most I've been able to narrow it down so far is that it might have something to do with jQUery UI.  Removing the jquery-ui css that came with the plugin makes the issue go away.  We use the plugin for input suggestions in the application.

Comment: I seem to have found the issue and it was embarrassingly simple: styling provided with the jquery-ui clashing with our styling. The ui-helper-hidden-accessible class contained within a text entry field was being set to silly dimensions due to sloppy css selectors! The difficulty finding it was due to dev tools not being able to select the hidden element and while looking through the elements the input did not extend to cater for the jQuery UI element. This is embarrassing!

Comment: Yeah, embarrassing for jQuery UI ;) Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the issue involved jQuery UI, css provided with the plugin and my company's css. We use jQuery UI for input suggestion in our app.

What seems to be happening was that a recent change in our html structure set particular elements height and width to 100%. This css happened to include jQuery UI's ui-helper-hidden-accessible class. The css provided with the plugin sets ui-helper-hidden-accessible to, amongst other things, `position: absolute;` and `clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);`. As the parent element was not explicitly set to `position: relative;`, the ui-helper-hidden-accessible element was overflowing, though due to the clip property it was not visible in the developer tools! Neither selecting the hidden element or clicking it in the dev tools elements tab would reveal how large it was.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Altering the css selector that sets width and height to 100%
2. Setting the parent element to `position: relative;`